# Duda sobre método reduce() de Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Tengo la duda de el método de Java 8 de **reduce()** , que no sé cuando hay que utilizarlo , ni su explicación real. Lo único que sé es que a veces , se utiliza como sustitutivo de **sum()** o **average()** por ejemplo. También se que recibe un **Tipo,BinaryOperator**. Pero me gustaría que alguien me pusiera un ejemplo o me diera una explicación más clara acerca de este método. 
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Una disculpa apenas veo tus comentarios, no extendí la response porque en ocasiones es difícil postear desde un dispositivo móvil, en este caso singular dejo mi respuesta tal y como la agregue, te comento que es buena pregunta la de tu comentario, la desventaja de  reduce() vs sum()  es  [Boxing](http://www.javahispano.org/certificacion/2011/11/4/clases-envoltorio-y-boxing.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys !!

Comment: Tal vez quieras echar un vistazo en [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) dentro de [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

[reduce()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) toma un stream (algo así como una lista) y lo reduce a un solo valor, usando un operador binario. 
Piensa como ejemplo las funciones de una hoja de cálculo que toman un rango de celdas y devuelven un valor, como SUMA(), PROMEDIO(), MAXIMO(), COUNT()...)

El operador (concretamente, del tipo [BinaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) ) se lo pasas tú, debe cumplir ciertas propiedades (asociatividad, por ejemplo).

> a veces , se utiliza como sustitutivo de sum() o average()

Claro, porque `sum()` o `average()` podrían verse como casos particulares. La documentacion menciona que [count()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) es otro caso especial.

Utilizas `reduce()` cuando necesitas aplicar otra funcion de reducción.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas novedades que ofrece java8 hay que pensarlas como facilidades para la paralelización de tareas. En concreto, de `reduce` hay que darse cuenta que la función de acumulación que se usa ha de ser *asociativa*. Ésto facilita que podamos dividir el *stream* en *substreams*, aplicar en paralelo a cada uno de ellos el *reduce*, y aplicar de nuevo la reducción sobre los resultados parciales para obtener el resultado final.

Esta estrategia ha dado pie a procedimientos como el **[map-reduce](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)** con distintas implementaciones como Hadoop o Spark, que son hoy en día la base de muchos de los procesos de cálculo masivo.

Es posible que el `reduce` no sea lo más adecuado para sumar una lista. En cuanto a *average*, cuidado porque ¡no es *asociativo*!. Para calcular la media hay que hacer por separado la suma y el contaje, y calcular con ambos resultados la media final. Pero no siempre se usan operaciones tan triviales.

Seguramente, si nunca se fuera a paralelizar, se seguiría usando el típico "bucle que va acumulando". Pero los nuevos sistemas exigen que el código esté preparado para la paralelización desde el principio.

Answer (score 0):

El método `reduce()`, es usado para realizar la suma de todos los elementos de un stream.

Estableciendo una analogía de lo que realiza el método `reduce()`, es como si obtuvieramos la suma de los valores de un array :

```
int[] numeros = {2, 4, 6, 8, 1};
int suma = 0; 
for (int x : numeros) {   
suma += x;  
}
```

> Cada elemento de la lista de números se combina iterativamente
>   empleando el operador de suma para generar un resultado.
>   Esencialmente, hemos "reducido" la lista de números a uno solo.

Mediante el método `reduce()` con un stream, de la misma forma podemos realizar la suma de los elementos  :

```
int suma = numeros.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Puedes revisar mas información sobre este método en la documentación:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/procesamiento-streams-java-se-8-2763402-esa.html

**Actualización: decido en esta ocasión dejar esta pregunta, tal y como la agregue originalmente,
en los link se tiene información aún más detallada sobre el uso.**

Comment: Pero para eso está el método sum() . ¿Qué sentido tiene?

Comment: Por lo que veo se puede concatenar strings ,y demás. Pero con respecto a la suma , ¿qué sentido tiene tener un método reduce() que haga suma , teniendo el método sum() ?

Comment: El método reduce tiene muchos más usos. No entiendo cómo apoyan a una respuesta que solo repite lo que está en la pregunta.

Comment: Acabo de despertar, tenía pensado revisar mis respuestas para mejorarlas como siempre lo realizo ya que aún no domino el español y me encuentro con este mensaje el cual me parece soez y ADEMAS ALENTAR A LOS DEMÁS A NO APOYAR LA PREGUNTA, porque "solo repite lo que esta en la pregunta". Recuerda que tu trabajo principal es administrar.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo @Elenasys , a mi ha servido un poco. Pero al menos me has ayudado. En cambio su principal trabajo , es administrar,como tu dices..Te doy las gracias Elena

Answer (score 0):

el metodo reduce lo encuentras en las Clases Stream se utiliza para recorrer un stream y retornar un solo valor , si tienes un stream que almacena Strings lo puedes reducir a la concatenacion de todos los objetos en el , asi mismo si guardas solo datos numericos

//se crea un nuevo stream con los valores "w","o","l","f"
Stream stream = Stream.of("w", "o", "l", "f");

//se declara una variable String la cual almacenara el producto de mezclar todos //los objetos que posee el stream 
//primer parametro inicio de la cadena
//segundo parametro (s,c) variables que se utilizaran (->)indica la expresion //lambda a realizar con los parametros
String word = stream.reduce("", (s, c) -> s + c);
System.out.println(word); // wolf

fuente : Oracle Certified Programmer OCP8
Espero te sirva 
Saludos.

Comment: Te recomendaria que agregaras un ejemplo de tu respuesta